# how to easy create xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have done this with Eclipse built-in editor, 
and with 'schemagen' and annotations from Java class.

Can this been done faster and more easily with some other tool,
i just need very basic xsd.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Some IDEs, like Visual Studio, allow you to load an XML file and have it automatically build an XSD Schema for you... Can't get much easier than that :)

Comment: This site can do XML to XSD
 http://www.flame-ware.com/products/xml-2-xsd/default.aspx

My IDE - Eclipse Galileo 3.5 IDE does not have this option but some Eclipse based IDEs like RAD
have this Generate option. 

But one very important question remains:
What will happen with optional attributes? 
If they were not present in original XML, then XSD will not have them too...

Comment: @reg, Yes you will need to learn a bit about XSD files and possibly tweak the auto-generated schema yourself. The best guide I've seen so far (although it's not perfect) is here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp Shame there's no tool that helps you construct a more complicated schema, you'll have to do it manually I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Free online tool that generates a basic XSD on a given XML:
http://www.flame-ware.com/products/xml-2-xsd/

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with any text Editor. Of course there are XML-specific tools like [Editix](http://www.editix.com/download.html) or xmlSpy by Altova. But if it sonly simple .xsd then I think [XMLFox](http://www.xmlfox.com/download.htm) will be fine.